# SHELL: Variable output

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I need help. I have this shell script that will output the hdd status, but the variable **$disk** is not read in the echo to show result.

```
 disk="sda1"
 echo -n $(df -hl | grep '$disk' | awk ' {percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'| column -t ):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
echo -n $(df -hl | grep "$disk")
```